# django.db.backends.postgresql error when try to makemigrations my django project

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I am trying to switch my Django database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQl, so I follow many tutorials to install and setup Postgres with Django project.

I did the following: `pip install psycopg2`, `pip install psycopg2-binary` and I modified the settings.py like that:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',

        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.postgresql',

        'USER': 'muusername',

        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',

        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',

        'PORT': '5432'

    }

}
```

Finally I maked my database, by running the command `python manage.py makemigrations`.
However, I got this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

**Please note** that I am also seccesufully install the pgAdmin in my OS which is Windows 10 in a first step.

I know that the problem is related by configuration of Postgres in my django project, but I don't know how to fix it, also I checked my djnago version which is the latest one, also, all needed packages are installed in my venv.

Comment: First check if you've created database and user in postgres after that you've to specify required fields inside your **DATABASES** configuration and ***NAME*** should be db name not  ***BASE_DIR / 'db.postgresql'***

Comment: I have changed the NAME, and also I have created a database and a user, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by just upgrade the django, as you can see here in the exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

Django ask the user to use mysql, oracle or sqlite3, but not the case of postgresql.
So this exception will be fixed when the user upgrade the django version.

I hope this answer can be helpful for someone another.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add like this in postgres:

```
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.postgresql', #You got that error because of this. This setting is for only sqlite3 not for postgres
```

Just add `db_name` in `NAME`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'your_db_name', #add your db name here
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_db_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, but still the same error

Comment: make sure you have installed postgres correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have actually downloaded the [PostgreSQL installer](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) itself and installed it.